# Broadcast message in WebSocket (Java)

Tags: java, websocket

WS Server code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websockets/broadcast-server")
@Local
public class BroadcastServer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BroadcastServer.class.getName());
    private final Set<Session> sessions = new HashSet<>();

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Received message: {0}", message);
        
        broadcastMessage("!!!BROADCAST!!! " + message);
        
        return "Echo: " + message;
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("* The session is open.");
        LOGGER.info("The session is open.");
        this.sessions.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("The session is close.");
        this.sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable error) throws Exception {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("* Error happen. " + error.getMessage());
        LOGGER.warning("Error happen. " + error.getMessage());
    }

    public void broadcastMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("Number of sessions: " + this.sessions.size());
        
        for (Session session : this.sessions) {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Unit test/WS client code:

```
public class BroadcastClientTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        BroadcastClient client = new BroadcastClient();
        client.connect(URI.create("ws://localhost:7001/ee-ejb/websockets/broadcast-server"));

        client.send("Hello World!");
        
        Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

}
```

If I run a few instances of above Unit test then each client sends a single message to the server and receive a single response.

But I expect to receive more messages because every message should be broadcasted to all clients.

It feels like for each client WebLogic creates separate WS server instance.

How to broadcast a message?

Comment: In output I got "Number of sessions: 1" for each WS client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcast in WebLogic was successfully done with following code:

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
    for (Session sess : session.getOpenSessions()) {
        sess.getBasicRemote().sendText("Echo: " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understood ,onMessage function is triggered when client sends a message. How  can a server broadcasts data, without being triggered by a client, to all open sessions?